# Windows Form size in the designer code does not match the size in the properties window

Tags: c#, winforms, size

The form size displayed in the designer for the form doesn't match the size displayed in the properties window for the same form and I can't seem to get them to match. Please see below screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Any idea why this is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client size of a form does not include the title bar and the borders.

The Size property of the form includes the title bar and borders.

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The size of the client area of the form is the size of the form excluding the borders and the title bar. The client area of a form is the area within a form where controls can be placed.

Answer (score 2):

What you see in Property window is `Size` and what you see in designer.cs is `ClientSize`. Size includes non client area also whereas ClientSize  doesn't include them.